# Why is the Casper update delayed?

Tags: casper

The update is scheduled to last year, but it is delayed.

Does anyone know the exact reasons?

Where is a related website?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Someone who's been keeping up with the Ethereum 1.0, 1.X, 2.0 differences can correct me and supply more detail, but I believe at least in the 1.0/1.X world, it was decided to roll Proof of Stake (Casper) and Sharding into a single feature release, rather than release them separately.

Clearly this is going to take a while to be feature-complete, so the initial schedule for PoS was pushed back.

---

The best website to (try to) keep up with everything is the research site: https://ethresear.ch/latest

Tags to watch would be "[Casper](https://ethresear.ch/c/casper)" and "[Sharding](https://ethresear.ch/c/sharding)".

Comment: Thank you for detailed information!